# How can I find specified string matching filter patterns with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I hava a pandas dataset called `tf` which has a column containing blank space seperated keywords titled "Keywords":

```
Name         ...                    Keywords
0  Jonas 0         ...                Archie Betty
1  Jonas 1         ...                      Archie
2  Jonas 2         ...          Chris Betty Archie
3  Jonas 3         ...                 Betty Chris
4  Jonas 4         ...                       Daisy
5  Jonas 5         ...                         NaN
6  Jonas 5         ...                Chris Archie
```

As an input I want to provide a set of strings to filter the rows by these keywords. I thought about using a list:

```
list = ["Chris", "Betty"]
```

I found out that I can filter rows if I make the list a string with the entries seperated by "|":

`t="|".join(list)`

and look for matches in that column with:

`tf[tf["Keywords"].str.contains(t, na=False)]`

This filters by finding ANY matching content, so the output is:

```
Name         ...                    Keywords
0  Jonas 0         ...                Archie Betty
2  Jonas 2         ...          Chris Betty Archie
3  Jonas 3         ...                 Betty Chris
6  Jonas 5         ...                Chris Archie
```

**What I want instead is:**

1. filtering by containing ONLY the list entries and
2. filtering by containing AT LEAST the list entries

For 1. the result should be

`3  Jonas 3         ...                 Betty Chris`

For 2. the result should be:

```
2  Jonas 2         ...          Chris Betty Archie
3  Jonas 3         ...                 Betty Chris
```

I found out that the following basically did the trick for 2.

```
a = tf["Keywords"].str.contains("Chris")
b = tf["Keywords"].str.contains("Betty")
tf[a&b]
```

However, I need to get this done generic as the list length and its entries may vary. I had a clumsy idea with a loop to intersect each  two consecutive list entries but that didn't work:

```
i = 0
while i < len(list)-1:
    a = tf["Keywords"].str.contains(list[i])
    b = tf["Keywords"].str.contains(list[i+1])
    tf = a & b
    i += 1
```

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Notice:*

*Dont use variable name `list`, because python code word.*

---

Solution if all keywords have only one word, no space between:

You can split all words by space and convert them to `set`s, so possible comparing by set converted from list `L`:

```
L = ["Chris", "Betty"]
s = set(L)

arr = np.array([set(x.split()) if isinstance(x, str) else set([]) for x in tf["Keywords"]])
print (arr)
[{'Archie', 'Betty'} {'Archie'} {'Chris', 'Archie', 'Betty'}
 {'Chris', 'Betty'} {'Daisy'} set() {'Chris', 'Archie'}]

df1 = tf[arr == s]
print (df1)
      Name     Keywords
3  Jonas 3  Betty Chris

df2 = tf[arr >= s]
print (df2)
      Name            Keywords
2  Jonas 2  Chris Betty Archie
3  Jonas 3         Betty Chris
```

---

More general solution working with multiple words in keywords:

```
print (tf)
      Name                  Keywords
0  Jonas 0              Archie Betty
1  Jonas 1                    Archie
2  Jonas 2        Chris Betty Archie
3  Jonas 3               Betty Chris
4  Jonas 4  Daisy Chris Archie Betty
5  Jonas 5                       NaN
6  Jonas 5        Chris Archie Betty

L = ["Chris Archie", "Betty"]
s = set(L)

#create pattern with word boundaries
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in L)

#extract all keywords and convert to sets
a = tf['Keywords'].str.findall('('+ pat + ')')
a = np.array([set(x) if isinstance(x, list) else set([]) for x in a])
#remove all matched keywords and remove possible traling whitespaces
b = tf['Keywords'].str.replace(pat, '').str.strip()

#compare only matched values and also empty value after replace
df1 = tf[(b == '') & (a == s)]
print (df1)
      Name            Keywords
6  Jonas 5  Chris Archie Betty

#same like one keyword solution
df2 = tf[a >= s]
print (df2)
      Name                  Keywords
4  Jonas 4  Daisy Chris Archie Betty
6  Jonas 5        Chris Archie Betty
```

Comment: Nice! Is there also a "matching any list entry" solution as mentioned in my post with your approach?

Comment: @Jonas - yes, use `df1 = tf[a.astype(bool)]`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more what you're looking for, pandas dataframe cells can actually contain lists:

```
import pandas

# Create a test dataframe
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    [
        {"name": "A", "keywords": "Something SomethingElse"},
        {"name": "B", "keywords": "SomethingElse Tada"},
        {"name": "C", "keywords": "Something SomethingElse AndAnother"},
    ]
)

# Split the keywords INSIDE the cell
df["keywords"] = df["keywords"].apply(lambda row: row.split(" "))

# Filter for a specific keyword
filter_terms = ["Something"]
filtered = df.loc[df["keywords"].apply(lambda row: any([term in filter_terms for term in row]))]

# Show the filtered results
print(filtered)
```

Comment: Thank you, interesting! Not initially a solution to my problem, but if I replace the "any" inside "filtered" with "all", then it looks like this is a solution to my problem nr. 1!

Answer (score 0):

Just add on the approach you implied to your Post with

Just Simulated DataFrame:

```
>>> df
      Name            Keywords
0  Jonas 0        Archie Betty
1  Jonas 1              Archie
2  Jonas 2  Chris Betty Archie
3  Jonas 3         Betty Chris
4  Jonas 4               Daisy
5  Jonas 5                 NaN
```

Using `str.contains` while using the names with `|` separated..

```
>>> df[df.Keywords.str.contains("Chris|Betty", na=False)]
      Name            Keywords
0  Jonas 0        Archie Betty
2  Jonas 2  Chris Betty Archie
3  Jonas 3         Betty Chris
```

Now, if we have multiple searches for names then applying pattern base search by constructing the regex by joining the words in `pattern` with `|`:

```
>>> pattern
['Chris', 'Betty']

>>> df[df.Keywords.str.contains('|'.join(pattern), na=False)]
      Name            Keywords
0  Jonas 0        Archie Betty
2  Jonas 2  Chris Betty Archie
3  Jonas 3         Betty Chris
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def compset(x, mylist):
    y = set(x.lower().split())
    if len(y.intersection(mylist)) > 1:  # == 2 for exact match
        return True
    else:
        return False

mylist=set('chris betty'.lower().split())

df['Keywords'].apply(compset, args=(mylist,))
```